# COM object error

Tags: vb.net

The error below prompted me after i installed the program which i have created in vb.net and right after i run a module in the program which runs a DTS in SQL server the error prompts me. Someone know this error? Thanks in advance!

COM object with CLSID {10020200-EB1C-11CF-AE6E-00AA004A34D5} is either not valid or not registered.

Answer (score 0):

Did you registered that component (DLL) using regsvr32 tool?

Comment: A COM object which is used in your application.

Comment: is it possible to install the DTSPkg.dll without installing the MS SQL server 2000?

Answer (score 0):

The message is probably trying to tell you that CLSID {10020200-EB1C-11CF-AE6E-00AA004A34D5} is either not registered with COM, or the dll/exe that it refers to is missing or damaged.

On my system, the COM component with clsid {10020200-EB1C-11CF-AE6E-00AA004A34D5} is the Data Transformation Services Package Object, which is part of SQL Server. You can check this on your system by running regedit and going to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID{10020200-EB1C-11CF-AE6E-00AA004A34D5}.

If this registry entry doesn't exist then its likely that you don't have Data Transformation Services installed, or the installation has become damaged. Try (re)installing it using your SQL Server media.

If the registry entry does exist, click on the InprocServer32 sub-key. The default value for this sub-key is the path to the DLL that implements the COM CLSID. On my system this is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\80\Tools\Binn\DTSPkg.dll. Does the DLL exist on your system? If it doesn't, COM won't be able to instantiate the COM object.

Bottom line: re-install Data Transformation Services.

Comment: is it possible to install the DTSPkg.dll without installing the MS SQL server 2000?

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible to re-install just DTS, as I only have SQL 2005, not 2000.

If the DTSPkg.dll exists on your system (it'll be in/under the main SQL server directory) then you could try opening a command box, CDing to the directory that contains the dll, and typing "regsvr32 DTSPkg.dll" (without the quotes). That will re-register the DLL and might solve the problem.

Really, though, your SQL installation is damaged. You should seriously consider re-installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the stack trace of the exception to determine exactly which line of code threw the error. You should be able to identify which COM object is failing.

How you fix the problem depends entirely on what COM object it is. For example, if it turns out to be a DTS object, then you could try re-running the SQL Server installer and selecting the "repair" option if there is one. You could also try manually self-registering the physical DLL if you can find it.